# I want to have my custom field use HTML, how do I do that?

Tags: content, html, custom-field

I want to have my [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) use HTML, how do I do that in such a way that I can use a rich text editor to view the content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin.

It's pretty easy to use and very powerful, so it's the best choice right now, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for resurrecting this 2010 question! And yes indeed, Advanced Custom Fields is the way to go in 2013. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I sometimes use Custom fields Template :
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/

You can attribute a type to your field (wysiwyg, list, image...)

Answer (score 3):

See this [example on github](http://github.com/bueltge/different-type) for an own meta boxes and add your specialy boxes for your type of content. You can also read [this post](http://wpengineer.com/1991/example-how-to-add-meta-boxes-to-edit-area/) for this example plugin.

[image: screenshot of the example plugin]

Answer (score 2):

http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/control-your-own-wordpress-custom-fields/

Found this, but I can't comment on whether the approach used is good or not, but it certainly covers what you want to do and more (storing and retrieving data that is not stored as post metadata.)