# Is there a way to get N number of WYSIWYG editors in a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, wysiwyg

Is there way to have multiple WYSIWYG editors for a custom post type?   For example, if I had a 2 column layout I wanted to have one editor for one column and another editor for the other.

Comment: What kind of WYSIWYG configuration do you need? The full panel incl. uploading images, fullscreen mode etc?

Comment: Related question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53/i-want-to-have-my-custom-field-use-html-how-do-i-do-that

Comment: Bueltge has a nice article that shows how that can be done: http://wpengineer.com/1991/example-how-to-add-meta-boxes-to-edit-area/

Comment: I need exactly this question answered for a client project. Thanks for asking!

Comment: MikeSchinkel - I'm new to WordPress; where do I put the code you posted?

Comment: @Alex - The code is in my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Say your custom post type was called `Properties`, you would add the box to hold your additional tinyMCE editor using code similar to this:

```
function register_meta_boxen() {
    add_meta_box("wysiwyg-editor-2", "Second Column", "second_column_box",
    "properties", "normal", "high");    
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_meta_boxen');
```

`wysiwyg-editor-2` is the ID that the meta box will have applied to it, `Second Column` is the title that the meta box will have, `second_column_box` is the function which will print out the HTML for the meta box, `properties` is our custom post type, `normal` is the location of the meta box, and `high` specifies that it should be shown as high in the page as possible. (Usually below the default tinyMCE editor).

Then, taking this as the most basic example, you must attach the tinyMCE editor to a textarea. We still have to define our `second_column_box` function which will print the HTML for the meta box so this is as good a place as any to do this:

```
function second_column_box() {
    echo <<<EOT
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#tinymce").addClass("mceEditor");
    if ( typeof( tinyMCE ) == "object" &&
         typeof( tinyMCE.execCommand ) == "function" ) {
        tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "tinymce");
    }
});
</script>
    <textarea id="tinymce" name="tinymce"></textarea>
EOT;
}
```

There are a couple of issues which I'm not sure of how to overcome. The tinyMCE editor will be nested inside of a metabox, which might not be ideal, and it will not feature the ability to switch between HTML and Visual editing modes, as well as the the media insertion commands which the normal post editor has. Switching the modes appears to be defined as a function who's first argument is the ID, but yet it also appears to coded into the wp-tinymce script. It is possible to use the built in tinyMCE functions to do so, but this changes the textarea between full tinyMCE and a basic textarea, without any of the WP HTML insertion buttons.

Comment: "Meta_boxen"? Awesome! I thought I was the only one. Gonna give you solution a try in a little while.

Comment: Thomas McDonalds solution is not working for me in 3.1 - is there a way in 3.1 to do this?

Answer (score 19):

First: **Big Thanks** to *@Thomas McDonald* for [**his answer**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/436/is-there-a-way-to-get-n-number-of-wysiwyg-editors-in-a-custom-post-type/439#439); I needed to figure out exactly the same question that *@Paul Sheldrake* asked and Thomas' code got me started in the right direction.

Unfortunately I then got stuck because **I needed to change the layout from the default** to a simpler and smaller layout since I needed to use the TinyMCE in a side metabox. I looked *practically* everywhere for a solution and especially on the MoxieCode [TinyMCE Wiki](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Index) and [TinyMCE Tips & How To Forum](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewforum.php?id=1) and found nothing! <sup>**[1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/436/is-there-a-way-to-get-n-number-of-wysiwyg-editors-in-a-custom-post-type/439#439)**</sup> Everything I found explained how to set `theme`, `width`, `height`, etc. using `tinyMCE.init({...})` but apparently you can't use that when you use `tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl")`.

I was about stumped when I ran across the article [**multiple TinyMCE 3 instances on one page**](http://hamisageek.blogspot.com/2007/11/multiple-tinymce-3-instances-on-one.html#comment-form) by [*Hamilton Chua*](http://www.blogger.com/profile/10046970730389911333), and he nailed it! His solution was to assign `tinyMCE.settings` before calling `tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl")`, for example:

```
<?php 
$id = "sidebar-content";
$script = <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#{$id}").addClass("mceEditor");
    if ( typeof( tinyMCE ) == "object" &&
         typeof( tinyMCE.execCommand ) == "function" ) {
      tinyMCE.settings = {
        theme : "advanced",
        mode : "none",
        language : "en",
        height:"200",
        width:"100%",
        theme_advanced_layout_manager : "SimpleLayout",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : ""
      };
      tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, "{$id}");
    }
});
</script>
<textarea id="sidebar-content" name="sidebar-content"></textarea>
EOT;
```

The sad part is this was really not hard, but it wasn't documented anywhere else I could find. It's amazing to discover almost nobody else has experienced this issue.

So anyway the above code generated the following second TinyMCE in exactly the format/layout that my client needed:

[image: Multiple TinyMCE TextAreas in the WordPress 3.0 Admin Editor]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20100912-042637.png))</sub>

So if you are using *@Thomas McDonald* code above you find you have any need to modify the layout be sure to check out Hamilton Chua's awesome article *(thanks Ham!)*:

- [**Multiple TinyMCE 3 instances on one page**](http://hamisageek.blogspot.com/2007/11/multiple-tinymce-3-instances-on-one.html#comment-form)

***P.S.*** If you do something even slightly wrong the TinyMCE may just not show at all. For example in my case I use `theme: "simple"` at first and I got nothing and it took me over an hour to realize that I just needed to use `theme: "advanced"`. So if you find TinyMCE is not working for you be sure to try changing things around, you may be having a similar problem. *(BTW, I haven't tried any other themes nor explored what else is available; if you find other themes that work do please let a comment below.)*

#### Footnote

**1**: *Very frustrating! After little more than a month with WordPress Answer I'm now expecting to find answers to all my questions as the same level of quality as here, and elsewhere I'm typically finding disappointment!*

Comment: Mike, you're missing an equals after `$script` and also there's no closing for your heredoc, ie. `EOT;`. Apart from the small errors it's a good working example.. ;)

Comment: @t31os - Thanks for letting me know. Not sure how I missed those; I usually test and then copy my answers from my working code. Go figure!

Comment: using this solution resulted in the normal visual editor being set SimpleLayout as well for me in 3.1.

Comment: @mfields - Bummer that 3.1 has broken so many things. :-(

Comment: Wanted to draw your attention to this article, as it may clarify some things: http://dannyvankooten.com/450/tinymce-wysiwyg-editor-in-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: Official example on how to setup multiple editors on the same page and with different configs: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/multiple_configs.php

Answer (score 2):

Since I found this article as the first result in Google, I just wanted to comment that WP now offers a function to handle this sort of task.

Within the `add_meta_box` function, add the following code -->

```
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() );
```

Wherever you want to add the TinyMCE editor

Reference: [`wp_editor`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor)

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

The default editor, tinymce, is loaded by a function in wp-admin/includes/post.php called wp_tiny_mce();  [Look in the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/post.php) at line 1350.  There is an array of settings at line 1478.  One of the options apparently designates the textarea selector to apply the javascript editor to.  I was reading [this post by Keighl](http://www.keighl.com/2010/01/tinymce-in-wordpress-plugins/) on his blog that pointed me toward it.  Read the article, and maybe there's a way to call wp_tiny_mce() in an admin section plugin and apply it to a second text area you create.

Answer (score 0):

I got it just by adding “theEditor” as class attribute to a textarea:

```
<div style="background: #FFF; border: 1px solid #CCC;"><textarea id="my_details_field" name="my_details" class="theEditor" rows="20" style="width: 100%;"><?=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_details', TRUE)?></textarea></div>
```